# How do I attach articles to a question or response in Cross Validated?

Tags: feature-request

I understand it's simple to post hyperlinks to articles within a post. However in some cases articles are no longer available online or are behind a paywall.

Would it be possible for Stack Exchange add an attachment feature to posts? Or barring that create a community library of articles?

Comment: Questions about general SE capabilities need to be posted on the [SE Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) because we cannot do anything at all about changing them here.  If a question requires readers to read a substantial part of an article, then (arguably) the question is not sufficiently well focused to be on topic here, anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If somebody owns the copyright to an article, and has it behind a paywall, they probably won't look kindly on SE posting it as an attachment in one form or another.  In addition, such a change would have to be implemented SE-wide by the developers.  Note further that it wouldn't be relevant for most sites.  So, while I see your point, I don't think this is going to happen.

If you need to refer to an article, I would say post a complete citation and a link, even if it's to a paywalled site.  Many users here are affiliated with universities, and can access such links.  If there is a short excerpt from the article, you may be able to quote it as 'fair use' (although, there's some ambiguity, as laws differ from country to country, and it isn't clear if US laws should apply--where SE is headquartered, or if those of the country of the poster, or the owner of the copyright).

Comment: Thanks gung. What a world it would be if we had free access to journal articles.

Comment: There is some work on that, @RobertF. Maybe someday...

Comment: @RobertF "What a world it would be if we had free access to journal articles." `https://sci-hub.tw` (the current mirror of [Sci-Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub)) will grant (most of) your wish.